# Pass contexual information in thread-safe manner | Python logging

Tags: python, logging

I have an application which writes logs to a file, however I want to extend it to include some contextual information - JobId for instance. I do not wish to add this to every single log line I have, so instead started looking at what python logging framework offers - [LoggerAdapters](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-loggeradapters-to-impart-contextual-information)

I tried to do a quick POC and not sure if it satisfies my use case:

```
import logging
import threading
import uuid


class MyLoggerAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        return "[" + self.extra['JobId'] + "] " + msg, kwargs


class Job:
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.job_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        job_id = {"JobId": self.job_id}
        self.logger = MyLoggerAdapter(logger, extra=job_id)

    def run(self):
        self.logger.info("log line here")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Initialize logger
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILE_PATH)
    logger = logging.getLogger('LoggerAdapterTest')

    # Create jobs and run in separate threads
    ...
```

The logger needs the 'extra' information to be initialized which cannot be available globally. I have two major doubts:

1. Is it okay to instantiate an instance of LoggerAdapter repeatedly?
2. How to use the existing framework to build a logger that is thread safe and can use some context information from some metadata present in the function locally? (example: job.get_id)

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use a filter with a thread-local, as in this example:

```
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import random
import threading
import time
import uuid

logger = logging.getLogger()
tld = threading.local()

def filter(record):
    record.jobid = tld.jobid
    return True

def job(which):
    id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    tld.jobid = id
    count = int(3 + random.random() * 4)
    while count > 0:
        logger.debug('%d doing work', which)
        delay = 1 + random.random() * 4 #delay between 1 and 5 secs
        time.sleep(delay)
        count -= 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(threadName)-10s %(jobid)s %(message)s')
    logger.addFilter(filter)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        for i in range(10):
            executor.submit(job, i)
```

When I ran it, it printed

```
2021-11-20 13:19:46,410 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 c97f6cff-9a7c-421a-8b7e-87a2dda71f8f 0 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:46,410 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 830d8302-55b0-40b7-aef9-699b0c3b470a 1 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:46,410 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 a49b4cc5-7f62-4956-830a-ca1c77e05c30 2 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:46,425 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 d10b1424-f76f-47f4-b246-83e82c283ec3 3 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:46,425 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 b185f470-0590-4f14-9554-b585b9ae45c6 4 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:47,949 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 b185f470-0590-4f14-9554-b585b9ae45c6 4 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:48,660 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 a49b4cc5-7f62-4956-830a-ca1c77e05c30 2 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:49,270 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 b185f470-0590-4f14-9554-b585b9ae45c6 4 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:49,946 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 d10b1424-f76f-47f4-b246-83e82c283ec3 3 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:50,525 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 c97f6cff-9a7c-421a-8b7e-87a2dda71f8f 0 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:50,868 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 830d8302-55b0-40b7-aef9-699b0c3b470a 1 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:51,553 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 d10b1424-f76f-47f4-b246-83e82c283ec3 3 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:52,642 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 a49b4cc5-7f62-4956-830a-ca1c77e05c30 2 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:52,814 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 b185f470-0590-4f14-9554-b585b9ae45c6 4 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:53,142 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 830d8302-55b0-40b7-aef9-699b0c3b470a 1 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:53,505 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 d10b1424-f76f-47f4-b246-83e82c283ec3 3 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:54,256 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 cee0c924-dae1-4d77-ae5a-36ecbfac2661 5 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:55,366 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 c97f6cff-9a7c-421a-8b7e-87a2dda71f8f 0 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:55,522 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 d10b1424-f76f-47f4-b246-83e82c283ec3 3 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:55,742 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 b185f470-0590-4f14-9554-b585b9ae45c6 4 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:56,414 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 830d8302-55b0-40b7-aef9-699b0c3b470a 1 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:56,679 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 c97f6cff-9a7c-421a-8b7e-87a2dda71f8f 0 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:56,982 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 cee0c924-dae1-4d77-ae5a-36ecbfac2661 5 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:58,399 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 d10b1424-f76f-47f4-b246-83e82c283ec3 3 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:58,745 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 830d8302-55b0-40b7-aef9-699b0c3b470a 1 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:58,823 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 c97f6cff-9a7c-421a-8b7e-87a2dda71f8f 0 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:59,057 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 cee0c924-dae1-4d77-ae5a-36ecbfac2661 5 doing work
2021-11-20 13:19:59,699 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 61cb18f5-30d5-4382-bce1-4f1b4f06a2b7 6 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:01,218 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 cee0c924-dae1-4d77-ae5a-36ecbfac2661 5 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:01,421 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 8dc93b28-6bd8-4183-808f-7bd61e8e425c 7 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:01,483 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 7d2f88fa-4d05-40bc-b3c1-607e9c3505bf 8 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:02,272 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 61cb18f5-30d5-4382-bce1-4f1b4f06a2b7 6 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:02,866 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 830d8302-55b0-40b7-aef9-699b0c3b470a 1 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:03,470 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 cee0c924-dae1-4d77-ae5a-36ecbfac2661 5 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:04,129 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 8dc93b28-6bd8-4183-808f-7bd61e8e425c 7 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:04,706 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 61cb18f5-30d5-4382-bce1-4f1b4f06a2b7 6 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:05,695 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 82e44096-19e1-48a7-991a-8e96d6e41a9a 9 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:05,746 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 7d2f88fa-4d05-40bc-b3c1-607e9c3505bf 8 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:07,190 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 7d2f88fa-4d05-40bc-b3c1-607e9c3505bf 8 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:07,224 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 cee0c924-dae1-4d77-ae5a-36ecbfac2661 5 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:07,872 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 8dc93b28-6bd8-4183-808f-7bd61e8e425c 7 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:07,876 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 61cb18f5-30d5-4382-bce1-4f1b4f06a2b7 6 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:08,658 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 82e44096-19e1-48a7-991a-8e96d6e41a9a 9 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:08,699 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 7d2f88fa-4d05-40bc-b3c1-607e9c3505bf 8 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:10,012 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 61cb18f5-30d5-4382-bce1-4f1b4f06a2b7 6 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:11,311 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 82e44096-19e1-48a7-991a-8e96d6e41a9a 9 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:11,763 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 61cb18f5-30d5-4382-bce1-4f1b4f06a2b7 6 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:12,315 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 8dc93b28-6bd8-4183-808f-7bd61e8e425c 7 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:12,677 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 7d2f88fa-4d05-40bc-b3c1-607e9c3505bf 8 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:13,883 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 82e44096-19e1-48a7-991a-8e96d6e41a9a 9 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:15,333 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 7d2f88fa-4d05-40bc-b3c1-607e9c3505bf 8 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:17,137 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 82e44096-19e1-48a7-991a-8e96d6e41a9a 9 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:17,295 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 8dc93b28-6bd8-4183-808f-7bd61e8e425c 7 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:19,960 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 82e44096-19e1-48a7-991a-8e96d6e41a9a 9 doing work
2021-11-20 13:20:21,940 ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 8dc93b28-6bd8-4183-808f-7bd61e8e425c 7 doing work
```

Note the consistency between threads and job ids. The pool has only 5 workers, so jobs 0-4 are shown initially, and when they complete, jobs 5-9 make an appearance.